# gVim not showing german Umlaute, but only in error/warning and other messages

Tags: gvim

I have added the following line some days ago to enable NERDTree and Tagbar fancy arrows.

```
scriptencoding utf-8
set encoding=utf-8
```

Everything works fine. It displays äüöÄÜÖ without problems in text files of any kind. But just today I have seen the following line not showing this character correctly:

```
Bereits bei der <e4>ltsten <c4>nderung
```

... which is the information message that undo it at it's last change.

Is there a way to keep fancy arrows and correctly display messages?

Removing `set encoding=utf-8` brings back Umlaute but also fancy arrows are gone.

Comment: http://superuser.com/q/207264/85228

Comment: Your file is encoded in ISO 8859. Is it possible to convert your file to UTF-8?

Comment: @RaphaelAhrens I have tried setting `fileencoding` to `utf-8` but the problem remains. Will try Christians solution next.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To let you guys know -- the solution from  Christian Brabandt posted in the comments worked for me. Thank you!

Here is the link again: https://superuser.com/q/207264/85228